# Is there a way to get the old pre-Google+ username for YouTube channels using the API?

Tags: youtube-api

Using the API, I want to retrieve the pre-google+ youtube username of a channel, i.e. the string that comes after
youtube.com/user/

I've tried using using v3's channel-> list API call but this does not return anything related to  pre google+ usernames. However you can set 'forUsername' to filter for a channel with a username so I wonder if it's still supported.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such `username`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/xen0ph0l , where the username is xen0ph0l and it redirects to the channel with the handle @Radoq

Comment: As https://www.youtube.com/@Radoq and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4oHAMXki4syCbswgaDbW6g source codes don't contain `xen0ph0l`, it doesn't seem that your problem can be solved.